# Using NPM or Yarn with Webpacker in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, yarnpkg, webpacker

I have been reading the Webpacker documentation for Rails to potentially use ReactJS in a Rails project. It says that Yarn is a dependency of Webpacker. But I noticed that NPM 5 has been upgraded to be as fast and efficient as Yarn. My question: Can I use NPM with Webpacker instead of Yarn and has anyone tried this before without any major issues?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a great guide here. I hope this helps.

https://itnext.io/how-to-use-webpacker-with-npm-instead-of-yarn-a8a764e3a8ab